# Removing default border around image

Tags: html, css

I've looked around for a while now and can't find a solution that solves this particular problem. I have an image (`<img...>`)on a webpage and when the image loads it has a 1px solid white (or very light grey) outline/border on the outside edge of the image. It's not around the image but on the outermost pixels.

[image]

The associated CSS is as follows:

```
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
float: left
```

I've tried using

```
border: none
border: 0
outline: none
outline: 0
-webkit-border-before: 0px solid #fff
-webkit-border-after: 0px solid #fff
```

and am stumped, the only way I've gotten part of the white line to disappear is by increasing the border radius to cut off the corners of the image. I've verified and re-verified that this outline is not on the image.

The original image:
[image]

The div containing this image (and other similar images without the same problem) has css as follows (if this helps):

```
text-align: center;
height: 60px;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
width: 270px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
padding: 0px 20px;
```

Comment: Is that image inside an anchor tag?

Comment: Can you recreate this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?  If you can, that makes it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: Verified and re-verified using what? Most of the picture viewers use white backgrounds.

Comment: If the border is part of the image (meaning there are just white pixels around), you'll need to set up `<div>` wuth that image as background with position `[-1,-1]`.

Comment: I will try creating a jsfiddle, the image is part of a sprite sheet so I'll need to isolate the image. @DreamEater I've used more than basic picture viewers to verify the image contents.

Comment: Upload the image on commercial Imgur installation for the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Posted the original image above, will try to post jsfiddle in the next 30 minutes or so.

Comment: You either have a border on `a` or `img` or this image is wrapped in some other `div`. Without any context/code it's really hard to say why you're seeing this border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the solution!

I originally had it as an `img` containing a class that referenced the image in our sprite sheet. By changing the `img` tags to a `div` and keeping the original reference, the borders were removed and the sprite correctly displays.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
border-width: 0px;
```

Comment: The OP has stated he already tried that, and several variations.